# nosetests confused by temp string object

Tags: python, nosetests, squish

The following function:

```
def test_1():
    assert str(squishtest.object.properties(squishtest.waitForObject(":my_button"))["text"]) == "Another button"
```

gives:

```
AssertionError: 
>>  assert str(<module 'squish' from '.../squishtest.so'>.object.properties(<module 'squish' from '.../squishtest.so'>.waitForObject(":my_button"))["text"]) == "Another button"
```

which gives me no information regarding what text the button actually contains.

However this works better:

```
def test_2():
    s = str(squishtest.object.properties(squishtest.waitForObject(":my_button"))["text"])
    assert s == "Another button"
```

as it gives:

```
AssertionError: 
    'My button' = str(<module 'squish' from '.../squishtest.so'>.object.properties(<module 'squish' from '.../squishtest.so'>.waitForObject(":startVentButton_Button"))["text"])
>>  assert 'My button' == "Another button"
```

What is the issue here? Is there a nicer solution than that chosen by me in the second example?

I'm running nosetests with the -d flag set.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would use something like this:

```
assert a == b, “%r != %r” % (a, b)
```

But wait, nose has a [shorthand](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html) like this: `from nose.tools import eq_`

So for your case, you will have:

```
eq_(str(very_obscure_obj["text"]), "Another button")
```